Transfer Existing Linkedin developer App (account is blocked) to another account
I have a LinkedIn developer app which was unable to access due to an account block. How can we transfer that app to another account?
Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Srini
I have spoke to linkedin Support team and they have directed me here.

FAQ: customer service questions/ "But I was referred here..." - ok, what's you programming question? "how do I access the blocked account" is for Linkedin support and "how do I get X from an account I can't access" is unlikely to be solvable.
